# Custom Model binder asp.net core to bind dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have following code to generate view. Those fields are supposed to be fetched from database to generate html elements. Field type could be string, bool and Array. On posting data how can I get back data to respective types? Can this be done using custom model binding ( IModelBinder ). I have been looking example but could not find one.

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Test()
        {
            var model = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {{"first", "firstValue"}, {"second", "secondValue"}, {"third", new[] {"arjun", "khadka"}}};
            //var view = new MyModel {MyDict = model};
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Test(Dictionary<string, object> mydict)
        {
            var model = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            return View(model);
        }
```

View:

```
@model Dictionary<string, object>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in Model)
        {
            @if (item.Value is Array array)
            {<select multiple="multiple">
                    @foreach (var neitem in array)
                    {
                        <option value="@neitem">neitem</option>
                    }
                </select>
            }
            else
            {
                <input name="@item.Key" value="@item.Value" />
            }

        }
        <button type="submit"> save</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: by using Dictionary<string,string> I am able to get data for input fields. Considering the case of multiselect for which i want to get array of data .

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto how can i achieve this for dynamic fields?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom model binder. You just need to generate the field names properly.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Value is Array array)
    {
        <select asp-for="@Model[item.Key]" multiple="multiple">
            @foreach (var neitem in array)
            {
                <option value="@neitem">neitem</option>
            }
        </select>
    }
    else
    {
        <input asp-for="@Model[item.Key]" />
    }
}
```

Comment: What about controller? Could you show some code please? I mean can I use dictionary<string, object>

Comment: I have still got null values. could you please see picture above